# D: byLine with remove (http) file?

Tags: split, d

I need to split remote file byLine with D.
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.csv

The examples show only how to work with files on FS. But can I work with remote files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std.net.curl.byLine`.

Example:

```
void main()
{
    import std.net.curl, std.stdio;

    string link = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.csv";
    foreach (line; link.byLine())
    {
        writeln(line);
    }
}
```